# Is there a way to know if a specific company uses Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Tags: discussion, so-enterprise, microsoft, ask-different

It would be helpful to know if large institutions use private Stack Overflow Enterprise instances. I think Microsoft does.

Does anyone know if Apple Inc. uses Stack Overflow Enterprise?

Is there a link to Stack Exchange documented customers?

Here is an example from Bloom: http://www.bloomenergy.com/customer-fuel-cell/

Comment: Why is that helpful? For who?

Comment: It would be helpful from a sales point of view. Most website puts logo's at the bottom of their products, look (X, Y, Z) are our customers. Example: http://www.bloomenergy.com/customer-fuel-cell/

Comment: They may also be contractually prohibited from doing so...

Comment: Catija, that is fine, just asking ;)

Comment: If it would boost their sales I'm sure they would have done so already.

Comment: ask someone that works there. I've heard from someone on a community slack that his employer has a SO Enterprise instance ;p

Answer (score 11):

<sup>*There isn't a published customer list, but I brought up the broader issue internally to start thinking about if and how we might address such questions — so in the meantime…*</sup>

Enterprise and Channels are both new products, so we don't really know (yet) how customers might feel about sharing their management solutions in general (or how we might share this information, if public)… so, while we are working our way through these issues, it might be prudent to defer answering these questions piecemeal until we can do so responsibly. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thank you Robert, even though the community down voted me. I appreciate your understanding. I believe that it would help other companies make a decision if they knew how much it is used else where.